# How to make it so the statement is (either or)?

Tags: python

Trying to make it so that if it isnt one of these, it gives that message. it usually always just gives this message as the code says all of them. I want it to be either or.

I've tried what is in the code, I tried to bundle the `if` statement with it, but to no avail.

Note, am very new to coding.

```
import random

a = random.randint (1,6)
b = random.randint (1,6)
c = random.randint (1,6)
sum = a+b
sum2 = a+b+c

jah = input ("How Many Dice Do You Want To Roll? 1, 2, Or 3? ")


if jah == "1": 
  print ("You Rolled A",a,)
if jah == "2": 
  print ("You Rolled A",a,", And A",b,". In Total, You Got A", sum)
if jah == '3':
  print ("You Got,",a,',',b,", And",c,". In Total, You Got A,",sum2)  

if jah != (1,2,3):
  print("please Roll Again.")
```

Comment: use a `if  .... elif ... else` statement

Comment: ```import random

a = random.randint (1,6)
b = random.randint (1,6)
c = random.randint (1,6)
sum = a+b
sum2 = a+b+c

jah = input ("How Many Dice Do You Want To Roll? 1, 2, Or 3? ")


if jah == "1": 
  print ("You Rolled A",a,)
if jah == "2": 
  print ("You Rolled A",a,", And A",b,". In Total, You Got A", sum)
if jah == '3':
  print ("You Got,",a,',',b,", And",c,". In Total, You Got A,",sum2)  

else:
  print("Please Roll Again.")``` like this?

Comment: `if jah ==1: #do something  
elif jah==2: #do something
elif jah==3 #do something
else : #do something`

Comment: thank you so much it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @mayeul-sgc mentioned in their comment, the solution here is to use an `if`, `elif`, `else` statement sequence here.

Let's quickly talk about the code you've written and how it executes.

```py
if jah == "1":
  print("You rolled a", a,)
```

This statement will execute if `jah == "1"` and then continue onto the next line (where you check for `jah == "2"`).

Logically this works fine since `jah == "1"` and `jah == "2"` are mutually exclusive (i.e. if `jah` is `"1"` then it can't also be `"2"`).

The trouble you're running into is that you want a condition which says "if it wasn't any of these options then do ...". You can add another exclusive condition at the end, or you can rely on a language construct which is tailored for this specific use case.

Let's first fix your current approach, I see you've got `jah != (1, 2, 3)` as your final condition. Unfortunately what you're asking is whether `jah` is not equal to *exactly* `(1,2,3)` (a tuple containing the numbers one, two and three). Instead, you can rely on the `not in` comparison available in Python to say `jah not in ("1", "2", "3")`.

```py
if jah not in ("1","2","3"):
  print("please Roll Again.")
```

Note that in addition to switching `!=` (which compares equality) for the `not in` comparison, we also changed the values to be strings (`"1"` instead of `1` etc).

The nicer solution, though, involves switching up your `if` statements to leverage support for `else` conditions.

```py
if jah == "1": 
  print ("You Rolled A",a,)
elif jah == "2": 
  print ("You Rolled A",a,", And A",b,". In Total, You Got A", sum)
elif jah == '3':
  print ("You Got,",a,',',b,", And",c,". In Total, You Got A,",sum2)  
else:
  print("please Roll Again.")
```

As you can see here, if `jah == "1"` then we will not need to check whether `jah == "2"` or `jah == "3"`. Similarly, if we've checked for all three of those initial conditions (1, 2 and 3) and not found a match, we will fall through to the `else` block and print "please Roll Again." as you would expect.

### Summary

1. It seems you were looking for the `not in` operator instead of `!=` for the final if statement.
2. You can rewrite your code using `if`, `elif` and `else` to make this even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, use if .. elif.. else.

Updated code below..

```
a = random.randint (1,6)
b = random.randint (1,6)
c = random.randint (1,6)
sum1 = a+b
sum2 = a+b+c

jah = input("How Many Dice Do You Want To Roll? 1, 2, Or 3? ")


if jah == "1": 
    print("You Rolled A",a,)
elif jah == "2": 
    print("You Rolled A",a,", And A",b,". In Total, You Got A", sum1)
elif jah == '3':
    print("You Got,",a,',',b,", And",c,". In Total, You Got A,",sum2)  
else:
    print("please Roll Again.")
```

More info [here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-if-elif-else)